# different front page on each domain

Tags: wordpress

i have three domains that redirects to one wordpress site (mypage.com ,mypage.eu and mypage.de). I want to set different front page for each domain.
I have something like this:

```
function change_frontpage() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ($uri == 'http://www.mypage.com') {
        $frontpage = get_page(1139);
    } else {
        $frontpage = get_page(186);
    }
    update_option('show_on_front', 'page');
    update_option('page_on_front', $frontpage->ID);
}

add_action('init', 'change_frontpage');
```

it works when i visit mypage.com but when i go to mypage.eu or .de it is still same frontpage

Comment: what is the value of $uri, when you visit 3 domains ?

Comment: i used a debug now and $uri value is just "/"

Comment: Then, which page is of id 186 ?

Comment: now it works...i used $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] for $uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` for $uri fixed my problem